# django-compressor compiles SCSS files in STATIC_ROOT/app instead of app/static

Tags: python, django, django-compressor

We're using `django-compressor` and the `django.contrib.staticfiles` app and we're having problems while running the django development server and working on our SCSS: the wrong SCSS files gets compiled. The versions that are in `STATIC_ROOT/app` are getting found rather than the versions in app/static. This makes it so that edits to SCSS in `app/static` aren't reflected in the compiled CSS.

Removing everything in `STATIC_ROOT/app` fixes the issue, but it causes much confusion if `collectstatic` is executed for some reason.

Is there a way to ensure that the app/static files are compiled rather than any existing STATIC_ROOT/app files?

We're using django-compressor 1.4 with django 1.6 and the following settings are used in the django settings file:

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
    'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
)
COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    ("text/x-scss", 'sass --scss'),
)
STATICFILES_DIRS = [] #default
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')
```

Comment: Can you share your `STATICFILES_DIRS` and `STATIC_ROOT` settings?

Comment: Just edited with `STATICFILES_DIRS` (which is just the default) and `STATIC_ROOT`.

Comment: What is `app` exactly? Is it a Django app, a Django project, or something else? Where does `app/static` live? And was it added to `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Thanks for the comments! `app` is a any of the Django apps that we're using in the project (they are in INSTALLED_APPS). For example, we have an app named `base` in `PROJECT_ROOT/base` with static files in `PROJECT_ROOT/base/static` (our project layout is similar to [this one](https://github.com/xenith/django-base-template))

Answer (score 1):

Your `sass --scss` comand in `COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS` does not explicitly state a target directory. Hence the default is used, which [seems to be `stdin` and `stdout`](http://django-compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings/#django.conf.settings.COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS).

Now, compressor documentation is not so clear what using `stdout` means; but, from the examples it seems the files will end up in [COMPRESS_ROOT](http://django-compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings/#django.conf.settings.COMPRESS_OUTPUT_DIR) (defaults to `STATIC_ROOT/CACHE` which in your case is `root/base/static/CACHE/`)

What I personally like is to explicitly state the in/out directories (to remain constant in different environments). Here is an example (using a [pyScss](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyScss/1.1.5) compiler, but the idea is the same):

```
scss_cmd = '{python} -mscss -A "{image_output_path}" -a "{static_url}" ' \
    '-S "{static_root}" -o "{{outfile}}" "{{infile}}"'.format(
        python=sys.executable,
        image_output_path=COMPRESS_ROOT,
        static_url=STATIC_URL,
        static_root=os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT),
    )

COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    ('text/x-scss', scss_cmd),
)
```

(sorry if digging up long forgotten issues)

Answer (score 0):

Use `django-libsass`:

```
COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    ('text/x-sass', 'django_libsass.SassCompiler'),
    ('text/x-scss', 'django_libsass.SassCompiler'),
)
```

https://github.com/torchbox/django-libsass

Make sure to configure `STATIC_URL` and `STATIC_ROOT` correctly as described in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/.

For example:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_collected')

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
)
```

Compressor will take care of the rest, appropriately depending on the `DEBUG` variable.